# How to add entries to Wiktionary programmatically?

Tags: mediawiki, mediawiki-api

I want to add new entries to Wiktionary programmatically. Is there a specific Wiktionary API or some sort of hacky way of doing that?

Answer (score 2):

Wiktionary entries are plain wikitext. You can use the edit API to add a new entry, but you'll have to figure out how to generate the right wikitext.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. Would you mind elaborating on how that would look like in code assuming I can produce the `wikitext`?

Comment: You can find some examples in the [API docs](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Edit/Editing_with_Python). (You would have to use `text` instead of `appendtext` since you probably want to override the page content.)

Comment: Of course there are all kinds of [libraries](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Client_code) which do the heavy lifting for you.